# Trouble with initializing a git repository in R with usethis and gitcreds packages

Tags: r, git, github

This website gives instructions for initializing a git repository using usethis::use_git() to initialize a git repository, gitcreds::create_github_token() with gitcreds::gitcreds_set() to get/set a unique token, and usethis::use_github to connect R Studio to github, which I was able to use to commit my .gitignore and .gitconfig files to github-> https://rfortherestofus.com/2021/02/how-to-use-git-github-with-r/.

I was able to create a .gitignore file that hides all of the files that were showing in my R Studio terminal, and use the instructions from above to connect my RStudio to github. However, R isn't recognizing any changes from .R files that could be committed to github on the Git tab in R Studio. Why might this be?

Comment: For all the uncommitted files, look up how to create a `.gitignore` file.

Comment: But if we're going to help you, you need to tell us what actual commands you ran, rather than just point to the web page you used.

Comment: I updated my comment based on your .gitignore suggestion and asking which commands were run. However, any file changes I make in my directory aren't showing up in the Git tab.